# P(A) $\subset$ P(B) implies A $\subset $ B proof or disproof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

P(A) $\subset$ P(B) implies A $\subset $ B proof or disproof.

I have a strange feeling this is false but I do not know. Something to do with P(A) $\subset$ P(B) seems strange since P(B) is itself a powerself with P(A) being a subset.

Comment: Presumably $P(A)$ means the _power set_ of  $A$, that is, the collection of all subsets of $A$, and not the _probability_ of $A$?

Comment: Think about what it says: *every* subset of $A$ is also a subset of $B$, does it imply that $A$ is itself a subset of $B$?

Comment: P(A) is power set.
A is itself a subset of A. I suppose. Hmm..

Comment: I know this has been asked before. Not finding it immediately.

Answer (score 8):

$A\in P(A)\subset P(B)$ so $A\in P(B)$. That is, $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: A $\in$ P(A) $\subset$ P(B) implies 
A $\in$ P(B) so that A $\subset$ B.
Okay that makes sense. Idky I wanted this to be false.